# Enum KeyError Function

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums

I am trying to access an function stored inside an Enum using it's name but I get a `KeyError`:

```
from enum import Enum

def f():
    pass

class MyEnum(Enum):
   function = f

print MyEnum.function  # <unbound method MyEnum.f>
print MyEnum['function']  # KeyError: 'function'
```

But it work if the `Enum` don't store func:

```
from enum import Enum

class MyEnum(Enum):
   a = "toto"

print MyEnum.a  # MyEnum.a
print MyEnum.a.value  # "toto"
print MyEnum['a']  # MyEnum.a
print MyEnum.a.value  # "toto"
```

I know I could use dict instead of Enum, but I want to know why Enum behave differently.

Comment: Functions are indeed treated differently, because they form the *behaviour of enum values*, not enum values themselves.

Comment: What is the problem you were trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is storing a number of function and accessing them later using their name, I changed my enum into a dict.

Comment: Yes, a dictionary is going to be a better option there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a function is the same as defining it. And if you define a function in an `Enum` it becomes a method of the `Enum` and is not taken as a value for enum.

The following enums `A` and `B` are completely equivalent:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> 
>>> class A(Enum):
...     a = 1
...     def f(self):
...         print('Hello')
... 
>>> def x(self):
...     print('Hello')
... 
>>> class B(Enum):
...     a = 1
...     f = x
... 
>>> B.f
<unbound method B.x>
>>> A.f
<unbound method A.f>
>>> A['a']
<A.a: 1>
>>> A['f']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 384, in __getitem__
    return cls._member_map_[name]
KeyError: 'f'
>>> B['a']
<B.a: 1>
>>> B['f']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 384, in __getitem__
    return cls._member_map_[name]
KeyError: 'f'
```

Functions are treated differently because otherwise it would impossible to define custom methods in an enum.